# SQL LEFT JOIN with one result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I try to do LEFT JOIN which returns only one result.
I have 3 tables

```
ITEM:
==== some fields ====

ITEM_MEDIA_MAP:
item_id: foreign to item
media_id: foreign to media
featured: boolean

MEDIA:
==== some fields ====
```

I am trying to get all ITEM elements and each thumbnail for an item. If an image is marked featured this is the thumbnail which was manually picked by the user.

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT ITEM.title,  MEDIA.* 
FROM "ITEM"
LEFT JOIN (
    select * from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP
    where id in (
        select min(id) from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP group by item_id
    )
    ) as item_id
ON item_id = item.id
LEFT JOIN MEDIA
ON MEDIA.id = media_id
WHERE "ITEM.id" = 1 
ORDER BY ITEM.date ASC
```

This query works and return only one result from the MAPing table. The problem is that I am getting the first image written in the database where I need to get the image marked **features=1** and only if I don't have such image to get the first one

I tried something like that

```
 SELECT ITEM.title,  MEDIA.* 
    FROM "ITEM"
    LEFT JOIN (
        select * from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP
        ORDER BY featured 
        ASC LIMIT 1
        ) as item_id
    ON item_id = item.id
    LEFT JOIN MEDIA
    ON MEDIA.id = media_id
    WHERE "ITEM.id" = 1 
    ORDER BY ITEM.date ASC
```

But this query returns only 1 result from the JOIN

Comment: To me this looks very close. I think the `order by` needs to be `DESC` rather than `ASC` and you'll be there.

Comment: There is no id in item_media_map

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with:

I need the first record where some_field=some_value and, if none is found, then returns this other_record.

I usually do the next:

```
select fields
from (
      select fields, 0 as forder from my_table where first_condition limit 1
      union all
      select fields, 1 as forder from my_table where second_condition limit 1
     )
order by forder
limit 1
```

Then you can ensure that the returned record, if exists, match the desired conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
select * from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP
    where id in (
        select min(id) from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP group by item_id
    )
```

but you need this:

```
select * 
from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP
order by featured desc, id
limit 0, 1
```

This will return a single row (at most) and it will return the `featured` item with the smallest `id` if the featured item exists. If it does not exist, then it will return the item having the minimum `id`. Also, instead of `select *` you might want to `select` only the columns you need to optimize your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION the two options. 
This way you will have 2 select statements, but no sub-select for each ITEM row., in the following way:

```
/* All items which have featured=1 row, join with that row */
SELECT item.* , media.* 
from ITEMS item JOIN ITEM_MEDIA_MAP item_data ON item.id = item_data.item_id and item_data.featured = 1 JOIN MEDIA med ON med.id = item_data.media_id

UNION ALL 

/* All items which have max(featured)=0 row, join with min_id */
SELECT item.* , media.* 
from ITEMS item JOIN 
(select item_id, max(featured) as `featured`, min(id) as `min_id` from ITEM_MEDIA_MAP
group by item_id) as item_data ON item.id = item_data.min_id and item_data.featured = 0
```